# Should I delete my questions?

Tags: discussion, deletion, closed-questions

I am not concerned about reputation. I would like to be a useful contributor, and gain knowledge from interacting with mathematicians. I have no formal training.
I posted 2 questions, learned a lot, probably all I could expect, and then they were closed. I tried to reformulate one of them, but it may be a lost cause.
Should I delete them?
[Does “i” have one value or two values?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4221642) 
[Definition of prime numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4221340)

Comment: The first question has been reopened.

Comment: Since I accepted an answer for each of these questions, I cannot delete them myself.

Comment: @ToMath however do remember users with >20 k ( around something like that) if 3 users with > 20k vote to delete the question the question will be deleted even if it has a accepted answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all I advise you until the question is total spam anyone should not delete their question if some person has answered that because then you are disrespecting the other people answer. Also do remember you can't delete a question if you have accepted one of the answers. So you can't delete these answers. Instead of consider deletion try to focus on improving so that there might reopen. In my view if someone wants to be a useful contributor he should not delete his bad question but edit them to make them good