# Asking and editing good questions, but still receiving more downvotes than upvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes, questions

Not a duplicate of [I have been banned from asking questions, what should I do?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24782/i-have-been-banned-from-asking-questions-what-should-i-do)

---

I edited and improved some Math StackExchange questions as much as possible, but I'm still receiving more downvotes than upvotes. My net score for questions and answers is below -20.

What should I do?

Comment: Questions are asked to get answers, not votes. Did you obtain good answers?  I think if a question is interesting to Math SE users, then highly likely you will get a good answer. If a question is boring, trvial and looks like homework, probably nothing can help.

Comment: I can tell you one thing you **shouldn't** do for sure, and that's erase the content of one of your questions, and replace it with completely different content ... and then do it again, to the same question! That's a good way to get yourself banned from the site entirely. (I refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4575889/the-diophantine-equation-x324-y5 and its edit history.)

Comment: You've asked this question before on math.meta. math.meta is also not a place to cry foul in hopes of empathy, when you haven't been entirely honest, as Gerry states above.  Better to wait out six months, than to risk being banned from the site altogether.

Comment: But I don't want to wait that long time.

Comment: You can try writing an email to the SE/SO support team, but it's *highly* unlikely your suspension time would be reduced @JovanRadenkovic

Comment: @Seiya there is no suspension in place for Jovan; the user has been restricted from asking new questions.  But if they continue to ask new questions, by replacing other low quality questions, with entirely new questions, they risk full suspension, perhaps network wide.  There is nowhere to email, either.  At the very bottom of most pages, there's a "contact us" link, to contact community managers.

Comment: Please have a look at [I have been banned from asking questions, what should I do?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24782/72031)

Comment: The question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442574/can-you-find-the-number-n-such-that-n-in-hexadecimal-and-the-square-of-n-i I asked on Math StackOverflow has a new downvote even after improving. What should I do?

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24782/72031 and must be reopened.

Comment: I find the proposal to wait (avoid using the site for some time) reasonable. IMO, the SO/SE sites are toxic by design, and require purification periods.

Comment: I'm banned even on StackOverflow and five of ten of my questions but only two answers have negative score. This is because my net score is also negative here. And the ban started without warning me after writing ten questions.

Answer (score 4):

What you should do is you should review the guidance on what to do when you are restricted from asking questions, and follow the advice there: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans

Specifically, I encourage you to edit your existing questions to improve them based upon the feedback you've received.  There are many ways you can improve your existing questions:

- You can review our guidance on how to ask a good question, and make sure you are following all of the guidance there: [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/14578)
- You can review all of the comments you've received on your questions, then edit your question to address all of that feedback.  When people ask for clarifications, revise your post so that it will be clear to anyone who encounters the question for the first time.  When people provide useful tidbits, you can add this information to the question, and provide useful background.  Once each comment is addressed, flag it as 'no longer needed'.

  Don't just append stuff to the end of the question, but revise it so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Remember, we are seeking to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful for others in the future.
- You can make sure that each question provide appropriate context.  For instance, provide motivation or the context where you encountered the question, provide some background to teach people about what is known about the subject, show what progress you've made, etc.

If you have deleted questions, you should improve them as well, to the best of your ability, and then when they are in good shape, if they might be useful, undelete them.

You should *not* edit existing questions to completely change the contents of the question, as you have done at all of [Illegal intrinsic error in MAGMA](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4575889/14578) and [How do you solve the Diophantine equation $x^2=y^3+3$ using the unique factorization domain of the quadratic field $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt3)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4609355/14578) and [On the sum of reciprocals of prime-balanced numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4569219/14578).  That is considered an abuse of the site.

Currently, you are restricted from asking further questions because the site's algorithm has decided you have asked too many questions that are low quality.  Asking here is a privilege, not a right.  I notice you wrote "But I don't want to wait that long time."  That comes off as a bit entitled.  Of course you don't want to wait; I can completely understand that.  But if the site allowed everyone to ask as many questions as they wanted, regardless of quality, then this site would be overwhelmed by low-quality questions.  We would turn into Yahoo! Answers or Quora, which would not be good for the health of the community.  I imagine you want to ask here because Math.SE is so valuable and because people often give useful answers here.  Part of what makes Stack Exchange sites such a valuable resource, and what makes answerers want to continue using this site, is that we have quality standards.  These quality standards exist to protect the health of the community.  So, you'll need to abide by those rules.  This means improving your existing questions and waiting some time before you can ask further questions.