# How can I resume asking questions on MSE?

Tags: support, post-ban

I was banned from asking questions in MSE because of poor rated questions or closure and deletion of questions. For this, I read The MSE meta Questions related to this topic(specifically this [I have been banned from asking questions, what should I do?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24782/i-have-been-banned-from-asking-questions-what-should-i-do)). It said that improving questions and finding reason for closure of those questions and rectifying them would allow me to stand a chance in regaining right to ask questions, also contributing positively will help, and undeleting self deleted post and editing it to make meaningful posts might also help, I tried to rectify my mistakes by doing this, so far, I also tried to contribute to site by answering questions, what else should I do more, as I have already edited my previous questions, but cannot improve it more because of already acquired downvotes in those questions

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that even if you have question ban, you're allowed to post 1 question after 6 months. (This is mentioned [in the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997) and, for example, in one of the answers here: [I have been banned from asking questions, what should I do?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24782))
So if the question after 6 months is received positively enough, perhaps it could be enough to get you out of the question ban.

Comment: are there any chances That the ban can be removed now by my work by any means?

Comment: @shadow,Yes I have read the question,It still doesn't specify what more work can I do to unban my account

Comment: There is nothing else to do. Either your improvements can help get out of the ban or you have already dug too deep. Be patient, you didn't get in the hole in a day, you won't get out faster.